# no nodes available to schedule pods - Running Kubernetes Locally with No VM

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes - I've worked with docker-compose until now (on one machine).
Now I want to expend my work to cluster of nodes and to get Kubernetes capabilities (service discovery, load balancing, health check etc).

I'm working in local servers (RHEL7) and trying to run my first Kubernetes environment (following [this doc](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/locally/)) with no lack.

I run:

```
hack/local-up-cluster.sh
```

then (In another terminal):

```
cluster/kubectl.sh config set-cluster local --server=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
cluster/kubectl.sh config set-context local --cluster=local
cluster/kubectl.sh config use-context local
```

And:

```
cluster/kubectl.sh create -f run-aii.yaml
```

**my run-aii.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aii
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: aii
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aii
        image: localhost:5000/dev/aii
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5144
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_IP
          value: kafka
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/script
          name: scripts-data
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /home/aii/core
          name: core-aii
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /home/aii/genome
          name: genome-aii
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /home/aii/main
          name: main-aii
          readOnly: true
      - name: kafka
        image: localhost:5000/dev/kafkazoo
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/script
          name: scripts-data
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /root/config
          name: config-data
          readOnly: true
      - name: ws
        image: localhost:5000/dev/ws
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      volumes:
      - name: scripts-data
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/infra/script
      - name: config-data
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/infra/config
      - name: core-aii
        hostPath: 
          path: /home/aii/general/core
      - name: genome-aii
        hostPath: 
          path: /home/aii/general/genome
      - name: main-aii
        hostPath: 
          path: /home/aii/general/main
```

Additional info:

```
[aii@localhost kubernetes]$ cluster/kubectl.sh describe pod aii-4073165096-nkdq6
Name:       aii-4073165096-nkdq6
Namespace:  default
Node:       /
Labels:     pod-template-hash=4073165096,run=aii
Status:     Pending
IP:     
Controllers:    ReplicaSet/aii-4073165096
Containers:
  aii:
    Image:  localhost:5000/dev/aii
    Port:   5144/TCP
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:  BestEffort
      memory:   BestEffort
    Environment Variables:
      KAFKA_IP: kafka
  kafka:
    Image:  localhost:5000/dev/kafkazoo
    Port:   
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:  BestEffort
      memory:   BestEffort
    Environment Variables:
  ws:
    Image:  localhost:5000/dev/ws
    Port:   3000/TCP
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:  BestEffort
      memory:   BestEffort
    Environment Variables:
Volumes:
  scripts-data:
    Type:   HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:   /home/aii/general/infra/script
  config-data:
    Type:   HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:   /home/aii/general/infra/config
  core-aii:
    Type:   HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:   /home/aii/general/core
  genome-aii:
    Type:   HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:   /home/aii/general/genome
  main-aii:
    Type:   HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:   /home/aii/general/main
  default-token-hiwwo:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-hiwwo
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  37s       6s      6   {default-scheduler }            Warning     FailedScheduling    no nodes available to schedule pods
```

docker images:

```
[aii@localhost kubernetes]$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
kube-build                                       build-47381c8eab    f221edba30ed        25 hours ago        1.628 GB
aii                                              latest              1026cd920723        4 days ago          1.427 GB
localhost:5000/dev/aii                           latest              1026cd920723        4 days ago          1.427 GB
registry                                         2                   34bccec54793        4 days ago          171.2 MB
localhost:5000/dev/ws                            latest              fa7c5f6ef83a        12 days ago         706.8 MB
ws                                               latest              fa7c5f6ef83a        12 days ago         706.8 MB
kafkazoo                                         latest              84c687b0bd74        2 weeks ago         697.7 MB
localhost:5000/dev/kafkazoo                      latest              84c687b0bd74        2 weeks ago         697.7 MB
node                                             4.4                 1a93433cee73        2 weeks ago         647 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64         v1.2.4              3c4f38def75b        2 weeks ago         316.7 MB
nginx                                            latest              3edcc5de5a79        2 weeks ago         182.7 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/debian-iptables-arm     v3                  aca727a3023c        5 weeks ago         120.5 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/debian-iptables-amd64   v3                  49b5e076215b        6 weeks ago         129.4 MB
spotify/kafka                                    latest              30d3cef1fe8e        3 months ago        421.6 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kube-cross              v1.4.2-1            8d2874b4f7e9        3 months ago        1.551 GB
wurstmeister/zookeeper                           latest              dc00f1198a44        4 months ago        468.7 MB
centos                                           latest              61b442687d68        5 months ago        196.6 MB
centos                                           centos7.2.1511      38ea04e19303        5 months ago        194.6 MB
hypriot/armhf-busybox                            latest              d7ae69033898        6 months ago        1.267 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/etcd                    2.2.1               a6cd91debed1        6 months ago        28.19 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/pause                   2.0                 2b58359142b0        7 months ago        350.2 kB
gcr.io/google_containers/kube-registry-proxy     0.3                 b86ac3f11a0c        9 months ago        151.2 MB
```

What is the 'no nodes available to schedule pods' means? Where should I configure/define the nodes? where and how should I specify the IPs of physical machines?

**EDIT:**

```
[aii@localhost kubernetes]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS    AGE
127.0.0.1   Ready     1m
```

and:

```
[aii@localhost kubernetes]$ kubectl describe nodes
Name:           127.0.0.1
Labels:         kubernetes.io/hostname=127.0.0.1
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 24 May 2016 09:58:00 +0300
Phase:          
Conditions:
  Type      Status  LastHeartbeatTime           LastTransitionTime          Reason          Message
  ----      ------  -----------------           ------------------          ------          -------
  OutOfDisk     True    Tue, 24 May 2016 09:59:50 +0300     Tue, 24 May 2016 09:58:10 +0300     KubeletOutOfDisk    out of disk space
  Ready     True    Tue, 24 May 2016 09:59:50 +0300     Tue, 24 May 2016 09:58:10 +0300     KubeletReady        kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:  127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1
Capacity:
 pods:      110
 cpu:       4
 memory:    8010896Ki
System Info:
 Machine ID:            b939b024448040469dfdbd3dd3c3e314
 System UUID:           59FF2897-234D-4069-A5D4-B68648FC7D38
 Boot ID:           0153b84d-90e1-4fd1-9afa-f4312e89613e
 Kernel Version:        3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64
 OS Image:          Red Hat Enterprise Linux
 Container Runtime Version: docker://1.10.3
 Kubelet Version:       v1.2.4
 Kube-Proxy Version:        v1.2.4
ExternalID:         127.0.0.1
Non-terminated Pods:        (0 in total)
  Namespace         Name        CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ---------         ----        ------------    ----------  --------------- -------------
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100%, i.e., overcommitted. More info: http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.md)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  --------------- -------------
  0 (0%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  1m        1m      1   {kube-proxy 127.0.0.1}          Normal      Starting        Starting kube-proxy.
  1m        1m      1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1}         Normal      Starting        Starting kubelet.
  1m        1m      1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1}         Normal      NodeHasSufficientDisk   Node 127.0.0.1 status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
  1m        1m      1   {controllermanager }            Normal      RegisteredNode      Node 127.0.0.1 event: Registered Node 127.0.0.1 in NodeController
  1m        1m      1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1}         Normal      NodeOutOfDisk       Node 127.0.0.1 status is now: NodeOutOfDisk
  1m        1m      1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1}         Normal      NodeReady       Node 127.0.0.1 status is now: NodeReady
```

But I got some free space:

```
[aii@localhost kubernetes]$ df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   47G   42G  3.2G  93% /
devtmpfs               3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  3.9G  3.7M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  3.9G   17M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-var   485M  288M  198M  60% /var
/dev/sda1              509M  265M  245M  52% /boot
tmpfs                  783M   44K  783M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0                56M   56M     0 100% /run/media/aii/VBOXADDITIONS_5.0.18_106667
```

How much disk space does it need? (I'm working in VM so I don't have much)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means there's no available nodes in the system for the pods to be scheduled on. Can you provide the output of `kubectl get nodes` and `kubectl describe nodes`?

Following steps descirbed in the local cluster doc should give you a single node. If your node is there (it should be) but just not ready, you can look at the log in `/tmp/kubelet.log` (in the future, if you're not using local cluster, look for `/var/log/kubelet.log` instead) to figure out possible causes.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've update my question with the details.. can you help?

Comment: `NodeOutOfDisk` means the kubelet will not accept new pods due to insufficient free disk space on the node -- since this is the only node you have, your pods can't get scheduled.