# How to add nodes if "kubectl get nodes" shows an empty list?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I am trying to run some installation instructions for a software development environment built on top of K3S.

I am getting the error "no nodes available to schedule pods", which when Googled takes me to the question [no nodes available to schedule pods - Running Kubernetes Locally with No VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396195/no-nodes-available-to-schedule-pods-running-kubernetes-locally-with-no-vm)

The answer to that question tells me to run `kubectl get nodes`.

And when I do that, it shows me perhaps not surprisingly, that I don't have any nodes running.

Without having to learn how Kubernetes actually works, how can I start some nodes and get past this error?

This is a local environment running on a single VM (just like the linked question).

Comment: If you are using k3s, it appears your installation is not proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend how your K8s was installed.  Kubernetes is a complex system requiring multiple nodes all configured correctly in order to function.

If there are no nodes found for scheduling, my first though would be you only have a single node and its a master node (which runs the control plane services but not workloads) and have not attached any worker nodes.  You would need to add another node to the cluster which is running as a worker for it to schedule workloads.

If you want to get up and running without understanding it, there are distributions such as minikube or k3s, which will set it up out of the box and are designed to run on a single machine.

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:k3s] although the question text doesn't mention that anywhere.

Comment: It's k3s. Edited.